# how can i change security name in django swagger specticuler?

Tags: python, django, swagger

[enter image description here][1]

please follow this image to clarify my issue
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ah0fD.png
how can i change security name like i got by default from Django swagger spectacular (jwtauth).i want to rename it so what i have to change in my settings.py file. please fixed my issue

in settings.py

```
   SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS = {
    'TITLE': 'title',
    'VERSION': '1.0.0',
    'SERVE_INCLUDE_SCHEMA': False,
    'CONTACT': {'name':'name','email':'noreplay@gmail.com'},
    'SCHEMA_PATH_PREFIX_TRIM': True,
    'SERVERS': [{'url': env('SWAGGER_SERVER')},],
    'PREPROCESSING_HOOKS': ["custom.url_remover.preprocessing_filter_spec"],  
    }
```

in django by default schema and swagger generation i am not able to solve this issue

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put this code in **views.py**:

```
from drf_spectacular.contrib.rest_framework_simplejwt import SimpleJWTScheme
    
class authtoken(SimpleJWTScheme):
        name = 'bearerAuth'
        priority = 1
```